# In Compojure-api how can I apply schema validation to the form-params of a particular route?

Tags: clojure, swagger, plumatic-schema, compojure-api

From the docs [compojure-api](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api#api-with-schema--swagger-docs)... Given

```
(s/defschema Pizza
 {:name s/Str
  :size (s/enum :L :M :S)
  :origin {:country (s/enum :FI :PO)
  :city s/Str}})
```

You can later in your code do something like:

```
(defapi app
  ...

  ...

(POST* "/pizza" []
  :return Pizza
  :body [pizza Pizza]
  :summary "echoes a pizza"
  (ok pizza))))
```

My question is how can this be accomplished for `form-params` of a route?

i.e.

```
(defapi app
  ...

  ...

(POST* "/pizza" []
  :return Pizza
  :form-params [pizza Pizza] ; <---------------- here
  :summary "echoes a pizza"
  (ok pizza))))
```

Answer (score 0):

form-params are like query-params, so you need to use the same syntax as for query-params, which means that it has the same restrictions/functionality.